# Python script keeps running in the background

Tags: python, ctypes

This is a simple script that is used to calculate Z scores of some neuropsychological tests.

But recently the code seems to be running on the background even after exiting the program. This problem didn't exist before, I use the following startup piece to ensure program is running with elevation, and is correct size for the display.

Program can be shut down using a "exit" command that raises SystemExit or just by pressing the X button on the top bar. Program keep running on the background regardless.

Where did I go wrong?

```
def progStructure():
    first_run = True
    if first_run:
        import os
        os.system("mode con: cols=160 lines=50")
        print("""
    ================================================
    PROGRAM GREETING
    ================================================
    """)

        mainStartup()
        first_run = False

    while settings("auto_run"):
        mainStartup()
        #this function contains the main program, but irrelevant to the question

    print("Auto shutdown enabled, program is shutting down.")

    wait(2)
    exit()
        #informs the user data has been saved then restarts


import ctypes, sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    progStructure()
else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, "", None, 0)
    progStructure()
```

My excel writing function:

```
def excelWriter(excel_path, data_num, printable_list):
    from time import strftime
    date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if settings("excel_output_subjectNames"):
        patient_name_local = patient_name      
    else:
        patient_name_local = "N/A"

    demographic_data = [patient_ID, patient_name_local, patient_admin, date, time, patient_age, patient_sex, patient_edu]

    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    wb = Workbook(write_only=False)

    try:
        test_name_list = [
                    "(1)MMT", "(2)MOCA", "(3)3MS", "(4)GISD", "(5)ECR",
                    "(6)Sözel Bellek Süreçleri", "(7)Rey Karmaşık Figür", "(8)İz Sürme", "(9)Stroop",
                    "(10)Wisconsin", "(11)Görsel Sözel Test", "(12)Renkli İz Sürme",
                    "(13)Wechsler", "(14)Wechsler-Sayı Dizisi", "(15)Sözel Akıcılık", 
                    "(16)Semantik Akıcılık", "(17)Saat Çizme", "(18)SDOT", "(19)Ayları İleri-Geri Sayma"
                    ]


        while True:
            try:
                data_workbook = load_workbook(filename = excel_path + settings("excel_name"), read_only=False)
                active_sheet = data_workbook.get_sheet_by_name(test_name_list[data_num-1])
                active_sheet.append(demographic_data + printable_list)

                data_workbook.save(filename = excel_path + settings("excel_name"))
                break

            except:
                for i in range(len(test_name_list)):
                    wb.create_sheet(title = test_name_list[i])

                wb.save(filename = excel_path + settings("excel_name"))
                data_workbook = load_workbook(filename = excel_path + settings("excel_name"), read_only=False)
                active_sheet = data_workbook.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")
                data_workbook.remove_sheet(active_sheet)
                data_workbook.save(filename = excel_path + settings("excel_name"))
                continue

    except:
        raise
```

Comment: Do you get the shutdown message? And what exactly are the symptoms of the "program still running"? Is it just that you see the Python executable still in the process list?

Comment: You don't have a complete example. Also, add print statements to see where it's getting stuck.

Comment: I can see the python executable still in the process list, yes. Either my exe if it's frozen, or the python itself, if it's just the script. I realized this after I tried to delete the program.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh The inner script doesn't/shouldn't have anything that could be running on the background, it's just bunch of inputs, then being saved into excel/txt files. Wait, can it be related to that?

Comment: @Bilal'Cheese'Akbulut, yes, likely. You have a potentially infinite loop there. First try to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. If you do, you will probably solve your own question.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Ah. Forgot to close the workbook, that seemingly fixed the problem. If the problem persists, I'll update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to close the excel file after writing, that seemingly fixed the problem, thanks for everyone helping out.